# javascript create nested object variable for saving from dotted representation

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested

I need to assign a value to nested object variable . The nested object variable will be given as

```
a.b.c
```

and the object will be given as

```
result
```

I need to create a variable

```
result[a][b][c]
```

so that i can bind value to this variable.  Initially the result object only initialized as
var result  = {}

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do it

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = "example";
var result = {};
result[a] = {};
result[a][b] = {};
result[a][b][c] = yourValue;
```

Comment: This works, yes. Is there any shorter way? Is JavaScript so strange, that we cannod do it directly?